Migrate to the new Firebase Cloud Messaging API for sending messages to a topic
I recently disabled the legacy Cloud Messaging API and switched to the new Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) as shown in the screenshot below:

Previously, I used the following code to subscribe a user to a topic and then send messages to the topic, and its work well:
...
@classmethod
def subscribe_to_topic(cls, device_id, topics: list):
    success = []
    for topic in topics:
        try:
            url = f'https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/{device_id}/rel/topics/{topic}'
            headers = _get_header()
            result = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
            success.append(True) if result.status_code == 200 else success.append(False)
            logger.info(f'subscribe user <{device_id}> in topic <{topic}> with status code: {result.status_code}')
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f'{e}')
    return all(success)

After switching to the new API, I tried to update my code as follows, but it didn't work:
...
    @classmethod
    def subscribe_to_topic(cls, device_id, topics: list):
        """Subscribes a device to a topic using FCM v1 API."""
        payload = {"registrationTokens": [device_id]}
        success = []
        for topic in topics:
            try:
                url = (f"https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/"
                       f"projects/{environ.get('FCM_PROJECT_NAME')}/topics/{topic}:subscribe")
                headers = _get_header()
                result = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
                success.append(True) if result.status_code == 200 else success.append(False)
                logger.info(f'subscribe user <{device_id}> in topic <{topic}> with status code: {result.status_code}')
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f'{e}')
        return all(success)

I have read the Firebase documentation, but I'm still unsure how to properly migrate my topic subscription and message sending functionality to the new API.
Could someone provide guidance or an example on how to achieve this with the new Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1)?
Additional Context:

The previous code subscribes a user to multiple topics and sends messages to those topics.
The updated code should use the new Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1).

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Here's how I resolved it (step-by-step) using the Firebase Admin SDK.

Install Firebase Admin SDK:
pip install firebase-admin


Authentication using Service Account:
Ensure you have a service account JSON file for authentication. Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to point to this file(Add it to the .env file (environment variables)):
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/serviceAccountKey.json" # got this from your firebase console project.


Update code to use Firebase Admin SDK:
Instead of manually crafting HTTP requests, use the Firebase Admin SDK to handle topic subscriptions and message sending.
Here's the updated code:
import logging
from os import environ
from firebase_admin import messaging, initialize_app, credentials

logger = logging.getLogger('firebase')


class Firebase:
    _firebase_app = None

    @classmethod
    def _get_app(cls):
        """Initializes the Firebase app instance."""
        if not cls._firebase_app:
            cred = credentials.Certificate(environ.get("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"))
            cls._firebase_app = initialize_app(cred)
        return cls._firebase_app

    @classmethod
    def subscribe_to_topic(cls, device_id, topics: list):
        """Subscribes a device to a topic using FCM v1 API."""
        _ = cls._get_app()

        for topic in topics:
            response = messaging.subscribe_to_topic(device_id, topic)

            if response.failure_count > 0:  # mean an error occured
                logger.info("Error")  # log its reason 

    @classmethod
    def unsubscribe_to_topic(cls, device_id, topics: list):
        """Unsubscribes a device from a topic."""
        for topic in topics:
            response = messaging.unsubscribe_from_topic(device_id, topic)

    @classmethod
    def send_to_topic(cls, topic, message, priority='normal'):
        """Sending message to a topic by topic name."""
        try:
            _ = cls._get_app()
            message = messaging.Message(
                data=message,
                topic=topic,
            )
            response = messaging.send(message) 
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error sending message to topic '{topic}': {e}")
            raise  # Re-raise the exception for handling



Usage:
Here is an example of how to use Firebase class:
device_id = "your_device_registration_token"
topics = ["news", "updates", "sports"]

result = Firebase.subscribe_to_topic(device_id, topics)  # First of all subscribe device_id to the topics...

topic = "news"  # Our desired topic

message = {
    "title": "Breaking News",
    "body": "Stay informed with the latest updates."
}

response = Firebase.send_to_topic(topic, message)  # Send message to the news topic
print(f"Message sent. Response: {response}")


Please refer this.
Recently , i also migrated from legacy to v1 , i have used admin sdk to sub /unsub topic.
Here's the link for installing admin sdk.
